# how can i get the class name?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i have an instance of IMethod type. i want to get the class name from it. How can i do that ....help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Eclipse API, but it looks like you should call `getDeclaringType()` to get an `IType`. You can then call `getElementName()`, `getFullyQualifiedName()` etc depending on your requirements.